# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 but everything is set to JDK 1.6

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I have a Maven Eclipse application which I'm trying to run through the command prompt using the following command:

```
java -cp target/classes;"target/dependency/*" com.example.Main
```

Unfortunately, it throws an error:

```
UnsupportedClassVersionError : unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I did some digging and found out it has something to do with the application being compiled on a JDK of a newer version, than the JRE it runs on. Apparently the 51 means it was built for 1.7, but I don't have a JDK 7 on my computer...

So I made sure that everything is set to version 1.6 :

system.properties file in the root contains

```
java.runtime.version=1.6
```

Added the maven property

```
<java.version>1.6</java.version>
```

Specified the maven compiler plugin in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I checked the version of my java using the command java -version which returned

```
Java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)
```

And an update of my project after setting the maven-compiler-plugin resulted in Eclipse automatically setting the compiler level to 1.6, the project facet level to 1.6 and adding the JavaSE-1.6 jre system library to my project.

So I have absolutely no idea where this JDK 1.7 is coming from. I never installed JDK 1.7 on this computer to begin with...

Also, originally, the maven-compiler-plugin wasn't present so it was build with 1.5 I guess. But I did a `mvn clean install`,  then a `mvn package`, and then tried the command again after all the settings were adjusted and it still throws the same error.

Comment: You are definitely missing something. Recheck your java version. Check on command prompt : `java -version` and `javac -version`

Comment: Maybe a dependency needs Java 1.7

Comment: java -version and javac -version both return 1.6.0_38, but I don't actually compile using the command prompt. I only use it to run my app. I'm compiling using Maven, and there I use the maven plugn.

Comment: Adrian, you're a life saver. My pom specified the wrong version of Jetty. Jetty 9 requires JDK 1.7, please post your response as an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: I use IntelliJ 14, and I don't include a compiler plugin.  I fixed this issue by removing the `target/` directory.  After that, worked just fine!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Probably you have a dependency that needs Java 1.7

Answer (score 14):

You're probably using a dependency which requires Java SE 7.

If this is the case either upgrade to Java SE 7 (recommended if you're using the JRE from Oracle without support contract, as Java SE 6 reached End of Life in February) or replace this dependency.

Comment: Yep it was Jetty 9. I can't upgrade to JDK 7 but I downgraded to Jetty 8 which does the job as well.

Comment: How did you downgrade the Jetty version?

Comment: @m.dorian by using earlier versions of jetty