# MojoFailureException on maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, onedrive

I just checkout this project https://github.com/tjeerdnet/OneDriveAPI

and my goal is to run it.

So I added to eclipse Kepler as I java project.

Then, I changed my project to a maven project (because I saw there is a pom.xml)

and I run it as Maven build with goal "install"

The console is displaying a bunch of compilation errors as below:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OneDriveAPI 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ OneDriveAPI ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ OneDriveAPI ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 22 source files to C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[3,38] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:3: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[4,33] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:4: package com.sun.jersey.api.client does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[5,33] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:5: package com.sun.jersey.api.client does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[6,33] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:6: package com.sun.jersey.api.client does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[7,32] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:7: package com.sun.jersey.core.util does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[12,17] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:12: package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[13,17] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:13: package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[15,24] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:15: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[16,24] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:16: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[20,26] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Logger
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[30,13] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Client
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[39,25] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Client
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[54,28] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MultivaluedMap
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[77,36] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:77: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MultivaluedMap
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[77,12] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:77: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClientResponse
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[91,12] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:91: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClientResponse
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[104,29] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:104: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MultivaluedMap
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[124,29] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:124: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MultivaluedMap
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
[ERROR] /C:/Grafica Specifiche/IntegrareOneDrive/OneDriveAPI/trunk/src/main/java/net/tjeerd/onedrive/core/OneDriveCore.java:[147,28] C:\Grafica Specifiche\IntegrareOneDrive\OneDriveAPI\trunk\src\main\java\net\tjeerd\onedrive\core\OneDriveCore.java:147: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MultivaluedMap
location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDriveCore
...
[ERROR] symbol  : class MultivaluedMapImpl
[ERROR] location: class net.tjeerd.onedrive.core.OneDrive
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Then I run my server and took those error log from my console:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main"
```

What is wrong with what I did?

I am very new to maven and JEE so sorry for the noob question

Comment: Your Maven plugin for Eclipse didn't download the necessary dependencies before compiling the project. Check your logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: thanks, I edited my question

Comment: I ll check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567514/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-but-everything-is-set-to-jdk-1-6 and get u back

Comment: Yes, you need a recent JDK installed. 51 corresponds to Java 7.

Comment: In my console, I am getting "Starting preview server on port 8080", where should I go to see my app? (there is no web.xml)

Comment: Seems as if some dependencies were missing in your pom. Execute `mvn dependency:list` in your project. Look at the results: There should be `slf4j-api`, `jackson-databind` , `jersey-client` and `jsr311-api`included among the dependencies.

Comment: I am getting a BUILD SUCCESS when running mvn dependency:list

Answer (score 0):

I have also some across a similar thing. The issue is with the java version. Make sure you are having the same java version(Major and minor) installed in your system in which the application is written.